# Scrolling up and down in the TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

Is there any specific function for scrolling up and scrolling down in the **TextArea**. "onscroll" triggers when scrolling up/down happens in the **TextArea**.

Also, how to go to the new line after the last line in the text area and put "dash"(--) when clicking(scrolling) down. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong but as I understand it you're after a function that actually programmatically scrolls the textarea for you. If this is correct the following works:

```
var scrollUp = function(elementId) {
    "use strict";
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.scrollTop = 0;
};

var scrollDown = function(elementId) {
    "use strict";
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
};
```

See jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WnHpj/3/

You can of course use **scrollTop** to move the scroll in smaller increments if that is what you wish.

I don't really understand what you are looking for with your last question, please explain further if you still want help with that.

**EDIT**

The dashes... add this function:

```
var addDashes = function(elementId) {
    "use strict";
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(element.value.substring(element.value.length - 4, element.value.length) !== "\n--\n") {
        element.value = element.value + "\n--\n";
        element.focus();
    }
};
```

See the updated jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/WnHpj/7/

Hope that is what you wanted.

Comment: My requirement is "When clicking on down button in text area, the cursor should go to the new line after the last typed line and put 2 dashes(--)". So, Any one going to comment can type after the dashes. Thanks.

Comment: @John Ah, I see. I've updated my post, hope that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#textbox").scroll(function(e){
 //this happens when there is a scrolling action in your element
})
```